# What is the request header by default in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to POST my data to a URL. I need to know what is the header that is sending by my request?

```
import requests
conf_json = {"key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2"}                    
r = requests.post(API_URL, json=conf_json)
```

I can get response header by `r.headers`, but I need request header and I don't know how I should get it. can you please guide me?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM As of right now, that link points to an empty line. It's better to give a permalink or link that points to a specific line in a specific commit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import requests
conf_json = {"key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2"}                    
r = requests.post(API_URL, json=conf_json)

# get request headers
print(r.request.headers)
```

Comment: API-URL is not a valid variable name due to the minus sign. Try making a different variable, like API_URL. You will have to define it first though, so API_URL = 'https://whereeveryouwant.go' and only then the request.post(API_URL..) part